# Internet connection stops after one interface is down in Ubuntu Server

Tags: networking, server, wireless, internet

I'm using Ubuntu Server 16.04 on a device with one fast ethernet interface and one wireless interface, both interfaces connected to LANs with WAN connection.

When the device is turned on/rebooted, the internet traffic flows from the fast ethernet interface (I found that out by issuing the "route" command).

When the:

- fast ethernet cable is disconnected or
- the fast ethernet internet is down or
- the fast ethernet interface is set to down

all the internet connection is lost, even if the wireless interface is up and with internet connection.

When I issue the "route" command after the fast ethernet interface is down, the "default" destination is either empty or filled with the fast ethernet default gateway's ip address.

To make the internet connection work I must manually add a default gateway route to the Kernel IP routing table or restart all the interfaces, and this sucks.

Is there any way for setting the internet connection work automatically like in Windows 7? What am I doing wrong?

My /etc/network/interfaces configuration is the following:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
# The loopback network interface

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# This is the Fast Ethernet Interface
auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

# This is the wireless interface
auto wlp4s0
iface wlp4s0 inet dhcp
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 172.16.1.1
wpa-ssid **********
wpa-psk **********
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: It's not a good practice to establish all DNS-servers at your network coming from external servers. At least one of them must be your router, e.g.

Comment: Thanks you for the tip, but am I ignoring internal servers by just setting these two dns ips? Isn't the third ip 0.0.0.0 by default?

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is not a DNS server, but is an address that means "everyone".  As you installed NetworkManager, it discarded /etc/network/interfaces settings.

Comment: > "It's not a good practice to establish all DNS-servers at your network coming from external servers. At least one of them must be your router"
Nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to fix that my installing network-manager and using it to manage my connections.
Apart from that I still don't know how to fix this behavior without installing external or lightweighter packages than NetworkManager.

Comment: NetworkManager.conf uses [dnsmasq](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/dnsmasq) as DNS internal server. That's why you solved this issue. dnsmasq will forward address queries to external DNS servers.

Comment: > Apart from that I still don't know how to fix this behavior without
> installing external or lightweighter packages than NetworkManager

You do, and you describe it above. Manage the routes directly. This is, in fact, what Network Manager *does*. This is very basic TCP/IP networking: there needs to be a default route; when that route is not working, no traffic passes. In order for